# VSCode: How to jump after Auto closing bracket?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, brackets

When I type ", for example, VSCode closes it automatically with second " and puts cursor in between the quotes, which makes me type the quotes content and then reach for -> key to skip the closing bracket. **Reaching -> key is much harder than typing " on my own.** So I wonder if I'm missing the intentional way to use auto closing brackets in VSCode.

**Is there an easy way to jump past the bracket, which appeared due to "auto closing", with out use of the -> key?**

For example, with Snippets one can press "Tab" to jump to another "input section" of the Snippet. But with auto closing brackets "Tab" just adds tabulation sign.

Comment: You can just type `"` and it will jump over that character.  It won't add another `"`.  Or whatever your bracket types are.

Comment: @Mark, thank you. This is useful! Unfortunately, this doesn't work with html closing tags like </td>.

Answer (score 1):

You can press Ctrl + Enter to jump to the next line and skip the closing tags.

Comment: what do you mean? + key will enter + sign into the editor

Comment: Sorry, I put close tag to highlight the CTRL and ENTER, but they just disappeared.